# PHP get specific keywords to variables from a piped mail

Tags: php

I am using this piece of code to pipe emails:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php

// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd))
{
        $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
```

In emails I need 4 lines starting with

```
---BEGIN---
data here
more data
ending with
---END---
```

I tried with explode and strstr but I am getting everything after the --BEGIN---
It doesn't stop at ---END--- somehow.

How I can "say" to it that I only need what is between ---BEGIN--- and ---END--- ?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/^.*---BEGIN---(.+?)---END---.*$/s', '$1', $email);
```